# Is my plan for a shed base on pre-cast concrete supports reasonable?

Tags: framing, foundation, shed

Will this work for a 10 x 8 plastic resin shed -

- 3 deck pyramid blocks on a side (corners and in center of a side) and two in center.
- Dig down 6 inches, tamp, gravel (have .5 to 1 in round stone on hand), level, deck pyramid on the gravel.
- 2 x 6 pressure treated wood, tie with metal angle ties.
  At least several cross members as well.

Surface is 3/4 OSX 4x8.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What's the purpose of the two blocks in the center? Unless they're support a beam, they only effectively support the individual joists they're under. I would't use them. Worst case scenario they cause bulges in your floor.

The metal angles are also unnecessary. The fasteners you use to connect the joists (galvanized 20d nails or 3" coated screws), along with the floor sheathing, are adequate.

Finally, ask yourself whether you actually need the pyramids. Your PT lumber is rated for ground contact, and raising a shed that high makes for access challenges. You'd probably need to build a ramp at least 4 feet long. I've built two such sheds at my homes and simply rested the 2x4 floor framing on a washed rock base. If you do that, lay housewrap or poly sheeting under the floor sheathing to protect it from excess moisture.

I don't know what "cross members" are, but blocking isn't really necessary for an 8' span, in my experienced opinion.

Otherwise, I think you have a good plan.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds great, except that I would space the blocks a bit closer together. Two possibilities:

4 10' 2x6, set ~ 2' apart (1', 3', 5', 7' relative to the 8' side) with blocks at 1', 5', 9'. That would give support for the crosspieces every 2' with the 2x6 spanning 4'. Total of 12 blocks.

5 10' 2x6, set ~ 2' apart (1', 3', 5', 7' relative to the 8' side) with blocks at 0.5', 3.5', 6.5', 9.5'. That would give support for the crosspieces every 2' with the 2x6 spanning 3'. Total of 15 blocks.

The 8' crosspieces could be placed 16" on center. Decking would go on top, your shed on top of the decking.

Keep in mind also that while one option is to get all the blocks level on the ground/gravel, the other option is to use short pieces in the middle of each block (size depends on the exact design of the blocks you use) that you trim to make essentially a grid of little posts-in-blocks that have the tops level. That's what I did for my deck - a lot easier than digging down.

You may also want to consider making the deck slightly bigger in one dimension so that you have space to stand on the deck in front of the door.

Comment: Two feet apart seems like major overkill unless the shed is holding engine blocks. A single 2x6 on edge will easily span the 3 feet or so that's proposed. If the wall sheathing extends onto the rim, all the more so.

Comment: @isherwood I'm concerned about the decking itself. A middle compromise might be 4 10' 2x6, 2' apart @ 1', 3', 5', 7' each supported by 3 blocks @ 1', 4', 7'. That would be a total of 12 blocks (up from 10 in the original plan, down from 20 in my suggestion) and the floor would never be more than 1' away from a 2x6 support underneath it.

Comment: I don't follow. I assumed a standard 16" joist interval.Where does the decking (sheathing) come in?

Comment: OK. I'm getting myself confused. Let me rethink this...